# Is it possible to prerender animation in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: animation

I have a `DensityPlot` which is evaluated for a long time. I wish to use it with animation, but it is absolutely inapropriate.

Is it possible to render animation first and then run it smoothly?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create an animation from DensitPlot results. I have chosen a simple Gaussian function to plot, but its center depends on a parameter `t`. Now I create a table of plots for many different values of `t`, and then I take several different steps to create various kinds of movies from it. The parameter `t` and its step size is going to be the main variable that you have to decide on depending on your application, in order to make a smooth animation.

**Note on speed**

To save time, you should execute the following commands in separate cells, and only choose the export or display method that you need. Otherwise the evaluation will probably stretch your patience.

```
exampleFrames =
  Table[
   DensityPlot[
    Evaluate[
     Exp[-((x - Cos[t])^2 + (y - Sin[t])^2)/.025]
     ],
    {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5},
    ColorFunction -> GrayLevel,
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 30,
    Frame -> None,
    PlotRangePadding -> None
    ],
   {t, Pi/50, 2 Pi, Pi/50}
   ];

rasterizedFrames = Map[Image, exampleFrames];

Export["movie.mov", exampleFrames];

Export["movie.avi", exampleFrames];

ListAnimate[rasterizedFrames]
```

What I did above is to first *rasterize* the individual frames before making the `ListAnimate`.

**Update:** thanks to Alexey Popkov for reminding me that `Image` can be used instead of `Rasterize` to perform the rasterization more efficiently.

Working with `rasterizedFrames` speeds up the `ListAnimate` process. This is especially noticeable if your movie has `3D` graphics as frames. Rasterization allows you in principle to customize the quality of the video frames. For the export as `.mov` and `.avi`, though, it seems to be faster to *not* use the pre-rasterized frames and instead start from the original `exampleFrames`.

If you want the movie in Flash format, do this:

```
Export["movie.swf", rasterizedFrames];
```

In the Flash file, rasterization leads to a smaller file size but the export takes longer for this format.

**Edit**

Thanks to @halirutan for pointing out that `Rasterize` gets much faster when replacing the above instruction by:

```
rasterizedFrames = Map[Rasterize[#,"Image"]&, exampleFrames];
```

**Update** In *Mathematica* version 9, though, I see no speed difference with our without the `"Image"` argument.

`ListAnimate` is the easiest way to create animations in Mathematica, but it can sometimes by so horribly slow that the notebook becomes unresponsive. This may happen if you have many frames with complicated plots.

That's why I also included some `Export` commands that generate movies in standard formats that can be read by other applications (media players). The file `movie.mov` should be a Quicktime movie, and `movie.swf` is a Flash animation.

Finally, depending on your operating system, it may in fact be best to create the movie in an external application. In that case, you can do the following:

```
Export["movie001.png", exampleFrames, "VideoFrames"];
```

This will create all the frames as individual files numbered movie001.png, movie002.png, etc. These can subsequently assembled in a movie editor.

If you want to go that route, that's a different topic that I have discussed some more on the following page:
[Mathematica image sequence export](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#ImageSequence)

Comment: +1 for the `"VideoFrames"` `Export` option. Didn't know about that one!

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can create a table of the plots at appropriate time intervals and then use `ListAnimate[]` on the table.

Comment: Your answer would have been even better if it gave a small code sample to show how it worked.

Answer (score 15):

Although the best answer is already accepted, I think something really important was not pointed out here. It's the existence of an `Image` type which was introduced in Mathematica 7. Everything I have seen so far points to that this type adds a significant improvement to rendering speed.

Therefore, when someone wants to convert a list of graphics into a rasterized format for fast rendering, the usage of `Rasterize` is not sufficient, since this does not create an `Image`, but a `Graphics[Raster[...]]` expression. The call to `Rasterize` should always be used with "Image" as second argument.

Please try it yourself with a list of 50 `DensityPlot`s similar to the one @Jens used in his answer

```
exampleFrames = 
  Table[DensityPlot[Sin[t x] Sin[t y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotPoints -> 30, Frame -> None, PlotRangePadding -> None], {t, 0, 2, 2/49.}];
```

And now compare the speed of calls to `ListAnimate` where the plots are converted to a raster format. You should use a stopwatch for this, since neither `Timing` nor `AbsoluteTiming` seems to be able to get the time correctly. First, with normal `Rasterize`

```
ListAnimate[Rasterize[#] & /@ exampleFrames]
```

This takes about 50 seconds here on my MacBook. Now, use "Image" to tell `Rasterize`, that it should create `Images`

```
ListAnimate[Rasterize[#, "Image"] & /@ exampleFrames]
```

This takes only 5 seconds on the same machine. Even the rendering seems to run more fluent from the beginning, where with the first version it seems to take some *loops* before the `ListAnimate` runs smoothly.

**Note** that even the export of a list of `Images` is faster than the export of `Graphics[Raster[...]]`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out this insane behavior of Rasterize. "Image" should be the default!

Comment: @Jens Applying `Rasterize[#,"Image"]&` and `Image` give identical results: `Image@# === Rasterize[#, "Image"] &@# & /@ exampleFrames`. It is documented behavior.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov That's not the point. In version 8 leaving out `"Image"` was much slower even if the result was the same! I think it's fixed in version 9.

Comment: @Jens The `Image` is still superior as compared to `Raster` at least in memory cosumption: `ByteCount /@ {Rasterize@#, Image@#} &@exampleFrames[[10]]`. Note that in both cases `ImageType` is `"Byte"`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Oh I think I misunderstood you the first time. Using `Image` is indeed better than `Rasterize`, and it's really versatile as I found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7556/245) too.

Answer (score 11):

You can also Export as video, see [this documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/MultimediaFormats.html).

Comment: How can this be used to pre-render an animation?

Comment: @rcollyer: Exporting to a file is prerendering, I'm not sure how else one would answer that question.

Comment: On a recent animation I did, I decided to convert the individual frames of the animation to `Image[]`s before feeding them to `Export[]`; it certainly went a lot quicker than running `ListAnimate[]` through those frames.

Comment: @BlueRaja exporting to a file presupposes that you have the frames generated, hence my question because the answer is incomplete without it.

Comment: My point was that if it takes a long time to do the computation, you might not want to repeat it each time you look at the animation.  You can compute the individual frames, export them, and watch (repeatedly.)