# Exporting animations under duration constraints for viewing on an iPad

Tags: export, animation

I would like to show some eye-movements data as animation on an iPad, in order to see the "gazes" as they occurred as a function of time.

Ideally, I would like to use and see `Graphics` objects only, not the dynamic controls.

I have about 50 trials with each 3000 gazes I would like to show. Preferably, all in one video with each trial looping 3 times.

Now, I have encountered many problems. To illustrate, this is equivalent to my situation except I`ll have about 50 different animations instead of 2.

```
pts = RandomReal[{-#, #}, {100, 2}] & /@ Range[2];
graphObj = {{Blue, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}, 
            {Red,Rectangle[{-.5, -.5}, {.5, .5}]}}

Manipulate[
 Animate[
  Graphics[{
   graphObj[[stimNo]],
   White, Line@pts[[stimNo]][[;; gazeNo]]},
   Background -> Black, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}],
 {gazeNo, Range[2, 100, 1]},
  DefaultDuration -> 3,
  AnimationRepetitions -> 1,
  AnimationRunning -> False,
  Paneled -> False],
 {stimNo, Range[2]},
 ControlType -> Setter,
 Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

QUESTIONS / PROBLEMS :

- I am not sure of the best format for the iPad and how I could play those animations.
- I have not been able to export the correct duration (3 seconds to see my 3000 gazes}.
- I could only achieve the above by exporting the `Animate` object itself, leaving me with the controls on the .mov.

My attempts to use `ListManipulate` have all failed so far.

I must say I have looked at all parts of the help menu related to exporting animations, but without success.

Comment: @R.M. "Exporting for the last 25 min... And I have no clue what is the time minute from info in your question, bu this is not gonna work if it is that slow.

Comment: @500 you might want to cut back on the number of frames you're exporting. 3000 frames in 3 seconds equals 1000 frames per seconds. A standard movie typically has around 25 frames per second.

Comment: @Heike, Thank You, I am confused as what I want is just what I see when using Animate[]. So you know how it reduce the sampling when constraining to 3 seconds with  3000 steps ?

Comment: For 3 seconds you want something like 75 frames, so you could generate a list of 75 images by doing something like `plots = Table[Graphics[ ...], {gazeNo, Floor[Range[75] Length[pts[[stimNo]]]/75]}]` for each of your trials and use that to export to for example a `.mov` file using `"FrameRate" -> 25`.

Comment: @Heike, Thank You very much, once again !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There exists no movie format on the iPad that can do a frame duration of `.001` seconds. 30 frames per second (as for NTSC video) is the fastest you'll be able to do, corresponding to roughly `.03` seconds per frame. This means your movies will be `100` seconds long if it has `3000` frames.

It is easy to export a list of frames to Quicktime (Apple's own format) if you run Mathematica on the Mac:

```
Export["movie.mov", frameList]
```

should do it.

For more control, you would follow [these instructions](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#Quicktime):

After making the list of frames by creating a `Table` of `Graphics` and calling the output list `frameList`, execute the following line:

```
Map[Print, frameList]
```

This will create all the plots conveniently bracketed in a CellGroup which you can select with a single click. With this, QuickTime export can proceed by selecting in the Frontend menu the item `Edit → Save Selection As.... Quicktime`.

If you want *even more* control, e.g., to select a different display duration for each frame, just use (assuming you're on a Mac) [the export function defined in the linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4903/245). To get a single constant frame duration `d` (in seconds), you'd invoke it as `exportMov["movie.mov", frameList, {d}]`.

If this *still* doesn't satisfy you, it's always possible to export the individual movie frames and use an external program to make the final movie, as described [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1435/245).