# Changing the speed of exported AVI videos

Tags: export, video

I am exporting an animation created using `Manipulate` in the `.avi` format. However the video runs very fast (I am putting it in Keynote). Its speed seems independent of how small I choose the step in `Manipulate`. Is there a way to control how fast the `.avi` will run or some other way to show the animation slower?

Comment: If you post a working code snippet of what you are trying to export you will also probably get much better answers (see for example how [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4727/does-mathematica-support-variable-frame-rate-for-any-video-format-in-analogue-o) was asked).

Comment: In this related question, "[Exporting Animations under Duration constraints to view on an iPad](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5460/245)", some other export methods are discussed.

Answer (score 29):

The trick is using a combination of `"FrameRate"`, an option of `Export`, and `AutorunSequencing`, an option of `Manipulate`. The former determines the number of frames/second of the movie whereas the latter determines how long a sweep of the control takes. With one control, that will be the length of the movie.

```
Export["output.avi", 
 Manipulate[
   Plot[Sin[k  x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
   {k, 1, 5}, 
   AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 10}}
 ], "FrameRate" -> 2
]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the `FrameRate` will not control the speed of sliderbar's velocity.Just take frame form oringnal fast video.

Comment: I don't think you read my post correctly.

Comment: What happens when I need `FrameRate` to be 0.5? To have a picture for 2seconds for example? I did not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

The option you need is [`"FrameRate"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/AVI.html). It's not even necessary to create a list of graphics objects first, as per [Sjored's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5542/745) answer.

Comment: You can `Export` a `Manipulate` as movie without creating an array. Try `Export["output.avi", 
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[k  x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 1, 5}]]`

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: but you can't control the speed of the movie that way afaik.

Comment: @heike please see my answer

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I stand corrected

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Me too:)

Answer (score 5):

I've found that giving the option "AnimationDuration"-> (seconds) in the Export function gives better results generally.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.  For instance, in what sense does `"AnimationDuration"` give better results?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Rather than reducing the framerate, it gives a longer animation at the same framretae, making it smoother.

Comment: I don't see this as an options at all

Answer (score 1):

You can use AnimationDuration to control this and a good FrameRate to make the transition smoother.

```
Export["output.avi", 
 Manipulate[Plot[Sin[k x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {k, 1, 5}, 
  AutorunSequencing -> {{1, 10}}], "FrameRate" -> 25, 
 "AnimationDuration" -> 15]
```

Video in: [Animation Video](https://youtu.be/DQ-wZtAcpqQ)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).