# Export Animate command to MOV video

Tags: export, animation, video

I'm trying to export a rather complex `Animate` command into a full-HD resolution video, but having no success so far. The animation has around 520 frames (the number of elements in the `trajectory` array). What I should be seeing is a tube object moving with a sphere object, and whilst I can see the animation is working with the `Animate` command, I cannot see the same results when I export the animation. I have tried different things but this just doesn't seem to work, I'm probably not using the export command in the right way. Instead of the 500~ frames trajectory of the tube and the sphere, I just see the animator moving from one side to other.

I'm using the `Export` function, in the following way:

```
Export["my_output.mov",animationObject,"QuickTime",ImageSize->{1920,1080}]
```

My animation object follows this pattern:

```
(*theta and phi work as a function of s (the only animated variable) to change the view point*)
theta = N[Table[q, {q, 0.1, 2 \[Pi], (2 \[Pi] - 0.1)/Length[trajectory]}]];
phi = N[Table[q, {q, 0.5 \[Pi], 2.5 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/Length[trajectory]}]];

Animate[
 Show[
  (*data is a static array of around 5000 points*)
  ListPointPlot3D[(*my list plot options and data*)],

  (*A tube *)
  Graphics3D[{White, Thickness [0.01], Opacity[0.4],Tube[trajectory[[1 ;; s]]]}],

  (*A sphere*)
  Graphics3D[{Yellow, Sphere[{trajectory[[s]]}, {0.02, 0.02}]}],

  (*Just showing some grids with 10 grid lines*)
  FaceGrids -> {(*Specific options for the face grids to show more lines, etc*)},

  (*ViewPoint changed according to the corresponding value of s in the theta and phi arrays*)
  ViewPoint -> Dynamic[{Sin[theta[[s]]] Cos[phi[[s]]],Sin[theta[[s]]] Sin[phi[[s]]], Cos[theta[[s]]]}],
  ViewAngle -> 50 Degree],

 (*Animate Parameters*)
 {s, 1, Length[trajectory], 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True,AnimationRepetitions -> 1, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

I'm using Mathematica 8 student version.

Comment: What if you try replacing the `Animate[]` with a `Table[]`?

Comment: Please always post the shortest code snippet that shows your problem. Nobody wants to scan 30 lines of Mma code to find out it was irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Please include sample data for `trajectory` and anything else needed to run this code.

Comment: Changing Animate for Table solved my problem, thanks so much @J.M.

Comment: Can you post that as an answer to mark it as the solution?

Comment: You can mark halirutan's answer; I didn't post an answer because "export to QuickTime is not available on Linux versions of *Mathematica*", so I can't test my suggestion out.

Comment: Sorry, I had my answer half way done, when I saw your comment. The thing that bothers me always in questions where the code is not running is, that you cannot try quickly your solution. Then you end up to write a short comment as tip/guess which is, if you are a bit experienced, very often the right answer. Then we are stuck with 2 things: (1) the correct answer is in a comment. Very hard for new users or visitors to find. (2) someone else creates his own test data to make the code valid and posts an answer. Then you get no score for it.

Comment: @J.M. In a good question, everyone can start by taking the code, trying things out and post his/her answer.

Comment: Here is a related question: [Is it possible to prerender animation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1428/245)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your code is not running due to the lack of `trajectory` and `data` it's not possible to give a verified solution, but the tips should help too. What you have to keep in mind is

- you don't need `Animate` because to export a movie, you can just give `Export` a list of images or graphics. Use `Table` in exact the same way where you have `Animate` and remove the `Dynamic` from your `ViewPoint`
- your static `ListPointPlot3D` does never change but you call it for every new frame. Store this (e.g. with a `With` block) into a variable and use this
- speaking of this: maybe it is better to create a list of images because they are usually faster to render than `Graphics3D` objects. This can be done by converting the `Graphics3D` you create with `Rasterize[gr, "Image",...]`. There you can specify your image size. If you only want to export it as movie, than it make in my opinion no difference, *where* you rasterize it.
- on the other hand 500 images of HD-size use a bit of memory, so maybe you have to try different things here if you run out of mem.

Finally, if you really want to create a movie of high quality, where you don't care about movie-size, than it's maybe worth to antialias the images before putting them into the movie. If you use a high-compression in your movie, then you can skip this since it maybe will not be visible any more. If you create your list of graphics with

```
With[{lp = 
    ListPointPlot3D[data, 
     PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.009], Opacity[0.6]], 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.6, 0.4}, {-0.4, 0.6}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, 
     SphericalRegion -> True, RotationAction -> "Clip"]},
  imgs = Table[
    Show[Graphics3D[{White, Thickness[0.01], Opacity[0.4], 
       Tube[trajectory[[1 ;; s]]]}],
     Graphics3D[{Yellow, 
       Sphere[{trajectory[[s]]}, {0.02, 
         0.02}]}], Background -> Automatic, 
     Boxed -> False, 
     BoxRatios -> 
      Automatic,
     FaceGrids -> {{{0, -1, 0}, {Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
         Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 0.1}]}}, {{0, 
         0, -1}, {Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
         Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 0.1}]}}, {{1, 0, 
         0}, {Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
         Table[l, {l, -1, 1, 
           0.1}]}}},
     ViewPoint -> {Sin[theta[[s]]] Cos[phi[[s]]], 
       Sin[theta[[s]]] Sin[phi[[s]]], Cos[theta[[s]]]}, 
     ViewAngle -> 50 Degree, ImageSize -> {1920, 1080}],
    {s, 1, Length[trajectory], 1}]
  ];
```

You can do in the export

```
Antialias[g_Graphics3D] := Module[{
   resolution = 72, factor = 2},
  ImageResize[
   Rasterize[g, "Image", ImageResolution -> factor*resolution], 
   Scaled[1/factor]]
  ]

Export["tmp/my_output.mov", Antialias /@ imgs]
```

Comment: Excelent answer Sir!