# Manipulate is evaluated slowly

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I have this function:

```
f[k_, θ_, ϕ_] := Cos[k*Cos[θ]*x + k*Sin[θ]*y - ϕ]
```

I want to change the parameters $\theta, \phi,$ and $k$ to see the effects on the function. I use the command below to achieve that:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f[k, θ, ϕ], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
{k, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}, {ϕ,0, 2*Pi}]
```

The problem is that when I change one of the parameters, say $\theta$, continuously the plot is evaluated slowly so that during the running you cannot see the actual graph.
How can I change those parameters and see the real evaluated result immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is not due to `ContourPlot` being slow per se.  It is because when controls are active, `ContourPlot` produces a poorer quality plot by default.  The plot commands are designed to interact with the dynamic system.  But ultimately, I think `ContourPlot` will be too slow to do what you seek.

The way to get nice detailed plot is to use the option setting `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"`:

```
  ContourPlot[f[k, θ, ϕ], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

However you will notice a considerable lag in response, especially as `k` gets bigger than `0.5` or `1.0` depending on the speed of your computer.  As far as I can tell, any plot with `k` bigger than `1.` will have to compute so many points and contour lines that the performance is bound to be unacceptable.

If you can be satisfied with `k` between `0.` and `0.5`, perhaps this will be satisfactory:

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[f[k, θ, ϕ], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, 
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[15, Automatic], 
  MaxRecursion -> ControlActive[0, Automatic], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
  {k, 0, 0.5}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

If your computer is moderately fast, you might try a higher number of plot points, such as `PlotPoints -> ControlActive[25, Automatic]`, for a slightly better plot.  ([`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html) switches the settings depending on whether a control is being moved.)

Note:  The contours are lines and can be computed directly, with a little bit of math and programming, instead via sampling the plane.  A faster way is possible, even if it is less elegant.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a movie of the changing graph? I mean it would be good if I could change the parameter k at each point and save the resulting graph and finally make a movie out of those many produced graphs.

Comment: @yashar Yes. See [Is it possible to prerender animation in Wolfram Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/is-it-possible-to-prerender-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the step for you parameters for Manipulate. In this case it will work much faster.
So instead of

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f[k, θ, ϕ], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
{k, 0, 10}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi}, {ϕ,0, 2*Pi}]
```

use for example:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[f[k, θ, ϕ], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> Automatic],
{k, 0, 10, 1}, {θ, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/20}, {ϕ,0, 2*Pi, Pi/20}]
```