# Speed up ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I created the following code, but the contours are drawn slowly with the movement of the slider, could you advise me how I should optimize the code?

```
Manipulate[ Module[{VF, VB, InvQ, K1, K2},
VF = 1/3/(p - 1);
VB = p*VF;
K1 = VB*(VB + VF)/(2 VB + VF)^2*2116800;
IncomeQ[q_] = InvQ /. Solve[q == 840 (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*InvQ, InvQ];
Income[q1_, q2_] = 3*(840*q1 - VB/(VB + VF)*q1*q1 - VF/(VB + VF)*q1*q2);
IncomeK = 
ContourPlot[{Income[q1, q2] == 529200, Income[q2, q1] == 529200, 
 Income[q1, q2] == K1, Income[q2, q1] == K1}, {q1, 0, 1700}, {q2, 0, 1700}, 
ContourLabels -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", ContourStyle -> Black];
demande = 
   Plot[{Tooltip[840 (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*q, "STC"], 
 IncomeQ[q]}, {q, 0, 1700}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1700}, {-30, 1700}}, ImageSize -> {250, 200}];
center =
RegionPlot[(Income[q1, q2] >= K1 && Income[q2, q1] >= K1), {q1, 0, 
 1700}, {q2, 0, 1700}, PlotPoints -> 20, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
PlotStyle -> Gray]; 
Show[demande, center, IncomeK]], {{p, 6, \[Beta]/\[CurlyPhi]}, 1, 11, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, TrackedSymbols -> p]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Does this help?
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/is-it-possible-to-prerender-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica

Comment: Dear @Elizabeth, your very nice code could be improved if you try to avoid the zeroes that eventually appear in th computation. For example, when we set (beta,phi) ->0 the program gives some computational errors. Changing (p-1) by (p-1.00000000000000001) woulb be sufficient to cinrcunvent this problem. In relation to the time o processing maybe you can plot some graphs in a same step....just a silly suggestion....good look!

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- `PlotPoints -> 50` will cause a significant slow down in ContourPlot.
- `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` is the default setting when a control is being moved.  You don't really gain anything using this setting inside `Manipulate`.  I use [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ControlActive.html) to switch between custom fast and slow settings for things like `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, when the default behavior is unsatisfactory.
- The proper syntax for the `TrackedSymbols` option is `TrackedSymbols :> {p}`.

The `ContourPlot` and `RegionPlot` in your code duplicate some of the calculation.  We can get a similar result with `ParametricPlot` using `MeshShading`.  `ContourPlot` generally does a slightly better but slower job, but see if `ParametricPlot` is good enough.  It is noticeably faster.

```
Manipulate[Module[{VF, VB, InvQ, K1, K2}, VF = 1/3/(p - 1);
  VB = p*VF;
  K1 = VB*(VB + VF)/(2 VB + VF)^2*2116800;
  IncomeQ[q_] = 
   InvQ /. Solve[q == 840 (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*InvQ, InvQ];
  Income[q1_, q2_] = 
   3*(840*q1 - VB/(VB + VF)*q1*q1 - VF/(VB + VF)*q1*q2);
  IncomeK = ParametricPlot[{q1, q2}, {q1, 0, 1700}, {q2, 0, 1700},
    PlotPoints -> ControlActive[25, 50],  (* change numbers to balance speed/quality *)
    MeshFunctions -> {Income[#1, #2] &, Income[#2, #1] &},
    Mesh -> {{529200, K1}}, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Black],
    MeshShading -> {{None, None, None}, {None, Gray, Gray}, {None, 
       Gray, None}}];
  demande = 
   Plot[{Tooltip[840 (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*q, "STC"], 
     IncomeQ[q]}, {q, 0, 1700}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1700}, {-30, 1700}}, 
    ImageSize -> {250, 200}];
  Show[demande, IncomeK]], {{p, 1.2, β/φ}, 1, 11, 0.2,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {p}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Note:* The default setting for `PerformanceGoal` is `ControlActive["Speed", "Quality"]`.  The setting `"Speed"` in plot functions reduces the number of `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, unless you set these explicitly.  So the setting `PlotPoints -> 50` overrides part of the `"Speed"` setting.

Answer (score 1):

One very simple suggestion would be to change the exact integers in your code to real numbers. Some guidance on why this is important can be found on this site [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18485/8).

This simple change certainly makes the automatic animation of this `Manipulate` run more smoothly than the original. The rest of your code looks fine to me: it's not obvious what else can be improved on.

```
Manipulate[Module[{VF, VB, InvQ, K1, K2}, VF = 1./3/(p - 1.0000001);
  VB = p*VF;
  K1 = VB*(VB + VF)/(2 VB + VF)^2.*2116800.;
  IncomeQ[q_] = 
   InvQ /. Solve[q == 840. (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*InvQ, InvQ];
  Income[q1_, q2_] = 
   3.*(840.*q1 - VB/(VB + VF)*q1*q1 - VF/(VB + VF)*q1*q2);
  IncomeK = 
   ContourPlot[{Income[q1, q2] == 529200., Income[q2, q1] == 529200., 
     Income[q1, q2] == K1, Income[q2, q1] == K1}, {q1, 0, 1700}, {q2, 
     0, 1700}, ContourLabels -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
    PerformanceGoal :> "Speed", ContourStyle -> Black];
  demande = 
   Plot[{Tooltip[840. (VB + VF)/(2 VB) - VF/(2 VB)*q, "STC"], 
     IncomeQ[q]}, {q, 0, 1700}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-.5, 1700}, {-30, 1700}}, ImageSize -> {250, 200}];
  center = 
   RegionPlot[(Income[q1, q2] >= K1 && Income[q2, q1] >= K1), {q1, 0, 
     1700}, {q2, 0, 1700}, PlotPoints -> 20, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> Gray];
  Show[demande, center, IncomeK]], {{p, 6., \[Beta]/\[CurlyPhi]}, 1, 
  11, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, TrackedSymbols -> p]
```

[image]