# Run command didn't work

Tags: windows, external-calls

I am trying to use external ffmpeg.exe to convert list of image files into mp4

```
a = Table[Plot[Sin[ω t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, ImageMargins -> .4], 
         {ω, .1, 2, .1}];

Export["movie01.png", a, "VideoFrames"];
Run["ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i movie%02d.png -c:v libx264  movie.mp4"]
```

But the conversion is not done. If I run the exactly same ffmpeg code in windows CMD, it works. What is wrong with the above `Run` command?

**solution**

It turns out that after adding new exe to the windows environment(in this case, ffmpeg.exe), we have to restart mathematica, or this new exe will not be recognized by mathematica.

Comment: Do your paths / $Paths match?

Comment: @Yves Klett yeah. Run["del file"] works well

Comment: ass @YvesKlett points out, you need to make sure that you reference the absolute path.

Comment: Why do you refer to the movie file as "movie01.png" in `Export` and as "movie%02d.png" in `Run`?

Comment: @m_goldberg This is the command of ffmpeg. see "https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Options" search "image2" you will find this.

Comment: @elbOlita I tried not working. and I don't think this is the point. Since `Run["del file"]` operate in the right directory. BTW, command like `Run["ffmpeg -i movie.mov -c:v libx264 goo.mp4"]` will convert correctly.

Comment: I believe this is some type of bug.  If you try running `Import["!node -p console.log('test')", "Text"]`  you get a similar non response.  You could probably work around this with Java.

Comment: @William I think "%" is suspicious, but I don't know how  to solve this

Comment: @matheorem Ignoring %, if it works in cmd but not in Mathematica then I think it fair to say this is some type of bug.  I'm unlikely to post a fix but it is probably likely Java or .NET will fix this.

Comment: @William I have no idea about java, Would you like to post an answer if you are convenient?

Comment: @matheorem This has been a pet peeve of mine so a hacked together a partial solution.

Comment: It appears we are having different issues apologizes if hope my posted solution doesn't work appropriately.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99564/run-command-correct-output

Comment: Perhaps the second section of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85586/280) can help to rewrite your `Run` argument in the correct form.

Answer (score 2):

Let's override the `Run` so it stops acting up.

```
Needs["NETLink`"];
InstallNET[];
Unprotect[Run];
Run[x___] := Module[{t, p},
   LoadNETType["System.IO.Directory"];
   Directory`SetCurrentDirectory[Directory[]];
   t = NETNew["System.Diagnostics.Process"];
   t@StartInfo@FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
   t@StartInfo@Arguments = "/c " <> StringJoin@Riffle[{x}, " "];
   t@Start[];
   t@WaitForExit[];
   t@ExitCode];
Protect[Run];
Run["ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i movie%02d.png -c:v libx264 movie.mp4"]
```

<s>Someone is welcome to convert this to .NET link but as it stands the following works for me.</s>  This is the old code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Run{
 public static void Main(String[] arg) {
    string command = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe";
    Process process = new Process(); 
    process.StartInfo.FileName = command; 
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + string.Join(" ",arg);
    process.Start(); 
  }
}
```

Compile it like so.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Run.cs
```

and run it like so in Mathematica

```
Run["Run.exe ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i movie%02d.png -c:v libx264  movie.mp4"]
```

Comment: compile shows cannot find “Wolfram.NETLink.dll”?

Comment: @matheorem Now try it. Sorry it is how I compile .NET links when starting a kernel from .net

Comment: This is great ! Thank you! upvoted. But still wish mma could fix this annoying bug

Comment: @matheorem I think it is a speed trade of(notice mathematica doesn't display a cmd window) maybe or at least they way they currently have it.  I'm not really sure though.  If I have time I'll try to convert it to a .NET link.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean it has something to do the disappearance of the cmd window?

Comment: @matheorem Ignore what I said, honestly I'm not sure how it is implemented.  I plan to send them a ticket/bug report at some point because this is an annoying bug especially because it gives no error and just doesn't run.  `Import["!echo test", "Text"]` doesn't display a command prompt window so I believe that gestures that it is implemented differently then the way .NET is implemented above, but surprisingly `Run["echo test"]` does display a command propmt window so simply put I'm not sure.

Comment: again, I have no idea about .Net link, seems it is much better, really hopes you have time :）

Comment: @matheorem It is about as good as its going to get.  I added the bug tag to your question.  Also filled a bug.

Comment: Does this fix your issue or not it still isn't clear to me.  Do you mind uploading a video somewhere so I can try to reproduce the bug?

Comment: You know what,  I am really confused right now. Since you asked me to provide an example to show the bug, it is actually shown in my question, so I run it again. But surprisingly, it runs without any problem now. I don't know what is going on. It didn't run properly before. And finally what I am sure is that your both methods in this answer works. Thanks for your answer, maybe I can catch this bug again later.

Comment: and for your problem. I run `Import["!echo test", "Text"]`, it didn't prompt a cmd window, but it did import the string. I am not sure if this is what you want

Comment: I got another case, it seems that your `Run.exe` is not working this time. first, download `http://www.7-zip.org/a/7za920.zip` it is 7-zip command line. After adding it to the windows environment, I tried this `Run["7z a -tgzip d:\\calc\\test.m.gz d:\\calc\\test.m"]` not working. While in cmd, this is working. Then I tried your method `Run["Run.exe 7z a -tgzip d:\\calc\\test.m.gz d:\\calc\\test.m"]` still no .gz generated.

Comment: Oh, my god. I finally understand what is going on. After I add new exe to windows environment. I have to restart mathematica, if not, it just doesn't recognize the new command. That is why I failed at first, but now it is OK after restart mma