# The second escaped path breaks command execution

Tags: string-manipulation, interoperability, command-line

Due to a terrible chain of events I had to reinstall part of my software. Git among it, but a newer version.

Something changed because earlier all four evaluations were giving me a version info:

```
gitPath = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe\"";
(*it is also on PATH*)
```

```
Import["!git -C \"C:\\Users\" --version", "Text"] (*using PATH, escaped*)
```

> "git version 2.9.0.windows.1"

```
Import["!git -C C:\\Users --version", "Text"] (*using Path, not escaped so not general*)
```

> "git version 2.9.0.windows.1"

```
Import["!" <> gitPath <> " -C \"C:\\Users\" --version", "Text"]
```

> ""

```
Import["!" <> gitPath <> " -C C:\\Users --version", "Text"]
```

> "git version 2.9.0.windows.1"

This basically means that calling git from Mthematica (via Import) is impossible unless you have it on PATH.

Which is **an acceptable solution** but **I would like to understand** what is the problem, the more that the third command works from a terminal:

[image]

Comment: Try `RunProcess`.  It did have several annoying issued in 10.x on Windows, but those might already (hopefully!) be fixed in 10.4.  You must specify the executable path and the arguments separately with RunProcess.  You can also set a working directory for the process.

Comment: @Szabolcs `RunProcess[{
  "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd\\git.exe",
  "-C", "C:\\Program Files",
  "version"  }]` seems to work, thanks, I tried once but wasn't motivated enough to check what should be escaped, what not, should I use `$SystemShell` etc etc.

Comment: I don't have Git and hence can't test but I think the issue should be the same as with `Run`. Please try my `wrapByQuotes` function from the second section of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85586/280) answer in the same way as I used it for `gifsicle`. Also you can be interested in the [post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00457.html) by Rui Liu (Wolfram Technical Support) linked there.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks, a lot of reading, I will take a look as soon as motivation and free time positively interfere.