# How to customize an animation

Tags: plotting, animation

I want to create an animation regarding the restricted three-body problem for the Earth-Moon system. The code is as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
r1 = Sqrt[(x + μ)^2 + y^2 + z^2];
r2 = Sqrt[(x - 1 + μ)^2 + y^2 + z^2];
Ω = (1 - μ)/r1 + μ/r2 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2) + (μ*(1 - μ))/2;

μ = 0.0121506683;
```

And here is the animation

```
P0 = Animate[ContourPlot3D[2*Ω, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
     {z, -1.5, 1.5}, Contours -> {C0}, ImageSize -> 500, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"C = ", C0}]], {C0, 3, 3.21}]
```

My questions now:

(1). I want to be able to inspect the changes in the interior region of the 3D surface. Any suggestions regarding the optimum `ViewPoint`. Is there a way to exclude the outermost surrounding surface?

(2). If I increase the `PlotPoints` to more than 50 the program crashes reporting an issue about the speed of the dynamic evaluation. How can I solve this issue? I need more plot points so as to obtain smoother and more detailed surfaces.

(3). How can I export the output in an .mp4 file?

Comment: As for the last part, please search the site (rather unsurprisingly) for "mp4".

Comment: Checkout [here] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1428/is-it-possible-to-prerender-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica)